# Query never stops fetching after refetching or invalidating

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, invalidation

Fetching for the first time works, same goes for resetting the query. The data is fresh right after, then becomes stale after 5 seconds.

However, I want to refetch or invalidate the queries after applying mutations, but whenever I do so, the data just keeps refetching and never returning:
[DevTools scr showing data just refetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93US6.png)

Same when i use the DevTools directly.

My useQuery hook:

```
export const useFetchCandidates = (id: string) => {
    
    return useQuery<Entry<IKandidatFields>[], Error>(
        'candidates',
        async () => {
            const res = await getCandidates(id)
            return res
        },
        {
            staleTime: 5000,
            cacheTime: 10,
        }
    )
}
```

Using the hook to access data:

```
const {
        data: candidates,
    }: UseQueryResult<Entry<IKandidatFields>[], Error> = useFetchCandidates(id!)
```

The mutation:

```
const mutation = useMutation(
        () =>
            sendCandidateToNextStage(candidateID, utlysning).then(() =>
                getCandidates(id!)
            ),
        {
            onMutate: () => {
                queryClient.cancelQueries(['candidates', id])
            },
            onSettled: () => {
                queryClient.resetQueries(['candidates', id])
            },
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by using a get axios request instead of utilizing the cms client directly... still don't know why the one works instead of the other when both of them return the same object.

When using the contentful API client:

```
export async function getCandidates(
    id: string
): Promise<Entry<IKandidatFields>[]> {
    const res = await client
        .getEntries<IKandidatFields>({
            content_type: 'kandidat',
        })

    return res
}
```

it was constantly fetching and never worked.

However, when using an axios request instead

```
export const getCandidatesFromAPI = async (id: string) => {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
        `https://cdn.contentful.com/spaces/${spaceID}/environments/${environmentId}/entries?access_token=${accessToken}&content_type=${contentTypeKandidat}`
    )
    return data
}
```

as the mutation function, everything worked perfectly.

Comment: what changes did you have to do to get it to work... would be nice to see the code that did work

Comment: Added the code now!:)